# How exactly does OptionalIntervalVar work in OR-Tools?

Tags: constraint-programming, scheduling, or-tools, c++

I created `OptionalIntervals` for a number of tasks:

```
    std::vector<IntVar> starts;
    std::vector<IntVar> sizes;
    std::vector<IntVar> ends;
    std::vector<BoolVar> presences;
    std::vector<IntervalVar> Intervals;

    for (int j=0; j<nbTasks; j++) 
    {   
        const IntVar start = cp_model.NewIntVar(Domain(0, tmax)).WithName("start");       // generamos una variable intervalo
        const IntVar end = cp_model.NewIntVar(Domain(0, tmax)); 
        const BoolVar presence = cp_model.NewBoolVar();
        const IntVar size = cp_model.NewConstant(duration[j]); 
        const IntervalVar interval = cp_model.NewOptionalIntervalVar(start, size, end, presence);
        starts.push_back(start);       
        sizes.push_back(size);     
        ends.push_back(end);
        presences.push_back(presence);
        Intervals.push_back(interval);
    }
```

and I want to maximize a function that depends on the `start` of each task (where some tasks could be unperformed to get a better solution).

For some reason, all the activities are unperformed in the results even if the start of a job is 53. I mean, the present variable is 0 but it has a start date (thus the constraint `start+duration==end` is not applied). Why?

I guess that what causes this is that the `starts` vector is independent from the `Intervals` vector, so when a task is unperformed the interval constraint is not applied but its start varies independently. Is there a way to avoid that? that if the task is not performed it doesn't have a start either.

Answer (score 6):

In the Python API there is a pretty good [docstring](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/2cb85b4eead4c38e1c54b48044f92087cf165bce/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.py#L1617-L1621) of what an OptionalIntervalVar is:

> An optional interval variable is a constraint, that is itself used in other
> constraints like NoOverlap. This constraint is protected by an is_present
> literal that indicates if it is active or not.

> Internally, it ensures that `is_present` implies `start + size == end`.

So you would have to constraint manually what happens to `start`, `size` and `end` when the presence literal is not active.

Don't forget to also constraint the presence boolean properly, otherwise it won't ever be active.